# Trigger Google signin function only when user clicks the button

Tags: javascript

Below code used for Google Sign in button on click. But, this function trigger on load every time instead of the trigger when the user clicks Sign in button. It affects user experience, by showing sign in the window even the user is not interested.

Above code works fine as expected other than onload function. Is it possible to load this function only when the user triggers Google sign in button? Until then don't load this function.

I am not sure how & which line of code to change from above Javascript.

**JS:**

```
//Google Sign in    
var googleUser = {};
window.startApp = function() {
  gapi.load('auth2', function(){
    // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
    window.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
      client_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
      // Request scopes in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
      scope: 'profile email'
    });
    attachSignin(document.getElementById('googleLink'));
  });
};

window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
  gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
};

window.attachSignin= function attachSignin(element) {

  window.auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
    function(googleUser) {
      console.log('Signed in: ' +
          googleUser.getBasicProfile().getName());
    }, function(error) {

  });

  // Listen for sign-in state changes.user
  window.auth2.isSignedIn.listen(function(user){
    googleUser = auth2.currentUser.get();
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    that.vue.onGoogleLoginProcess();
  });
}

window.onload=(function(){
  startApp();
}).bind(this);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="googleLink" class="customGPlusSignIn">
    <span>Sign in with Google</span>
</div>
```

Comment: try window.gapi.load('auth2', function() {...

Answer (score 0):

Just remove below code snippet.

```
window.onload=(function(){
  startApp();
}).bind(this);
```

And add `onclick="startApp();"` in `div` as below.

```
<div id="googleLink" class="customGPlusSignIn" onclick="startApp();">
    <span>Sign in with Google</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: gapi is not defined" in this line window.startApp = function () {
        gapi.load('auth2', function () {

Comment: After adding window.   --> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of undefined

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove  function

```
window.onload
```

And add `onclick="startApp();"` in `div` .

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: gapi is not defined" in this line window.startApp = function () { gapi.load('auth2', function () {

Comment: yes you are right but he want to fire the function on click of div tag so we suggest the way of this we also ignore the "Uncaught ReferenceError" because it already come through his codding